# Check if the binary file contains at least the contents of the second file

Tags: c, file

I tried to read 2 binary file and check if one file has at least the content of the second file(Not necessarily the same completely).

What I had tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *file1, *file2;
    file1 = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    file2 = fopen(argv[2], "rb");

    if(file1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: can't open file number one.\n");
    }
    if(file2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: can't open file number two.\n");
    }
    else
    {
    /* if the files can open... start to check... */
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is your specific question? The code you have shown does not do much at all. It does not attempt the actual checking logic. So are you asking us to just do the work for you? You are more likely to get an answer if you make a *genuine* attempt or at least ask a specific question.

Comment: I want to compare two files binary least the first file 's content will equal two but not completely. Examle in text file: the first file content: abc and the second file content:fdsdfsdfsabc... something like this but in binary

Comment: That's what you want to do. But that is not a question. You have to ask us about the specific thing that you do not know how to do. We can help you write the code yourself but we won't just write the code for you. Do you know how to read from a file? Do you now how to compare data buffers? What is it *specifically* you do not know how to do that you need help with?

Comment: I 'd appreciate it if you could give me direction to strat. I know how to check if the files are the same but I want to check at least and not *completely the same*

Comment: Keep It Stupid Simple: if the second file is small enough to load it in memory, sequentially browse first file looking for first byte from second one. When you got it, carefully compare all remaining bytes: if they are the same, you found it, if they differ later, just continue the search on first file. If you hit the end of first file, second is not contained in first.

Comment: You also have to define _how much_ of the contents the second file should be contained in the first file, in terms of lower limit or minimum. If you put it as low as few bytes you can get funny results. The first file may also contain not one but multiple fragments of the second file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare the 2 files character by character (it doesn't matter if it's binary or text) and use a function that steps through the 2 files and compare character by character.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void compare(FILE *, FILE *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *file1, *file2;

    file1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (file1 == NULL) {
        printf("Error: can't open file number one.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    file2 = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    if (file2 == NULL) {
        printf("Error: can't open file number two.\n");
        fclose(file1);
        return 0;
    }

    if ((file1 != NULL) && (file2 != NULL)) {
        compare(file1, file2);
    }
}

/*
 * compare two binary files
 */
void compare(FILE *file1, FILE *file2) {
    char ch1, ch2;
    int flag = 0;

    while (((ch1 = fgetc(file1)) != EOF) && ((ch2 = fgetc(file2)) != EOF)) {
        /*
          * if equal then continue by comparing till the end of files
          */
        if (ch1 == ch2) {
            flag = 1;
            continue;
        }
            /*
              * If not equal then returns the byte position
              */
        else {
            fseek(file1, -1, SEEK_CUR);
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (flag == 0) {
        printf("Two files are not equal :  byte position at which two files differ is %d\n", ftell(file1) + 1);
    }
    else {
        printf("Two files are Equal\n");
    }
}
```

Test

```
$ ./a.out a.out a2.out
Two files are not equal :  byte position at which two files differ is 209
$ cp a.out a2.out
$ ./a.out a.out a2.out
Two files are Equal
```